# Seeking [answers] about these tags on meta

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-request

As well as [answers](/questions/tagged/answers), there's [answering-advice](/questions/tagged/answering-advice), [appropriate-answers](/questions/tagged/appropriate-answers), [accepted-answer](/questions/tagged/accepted-answer), [unanswered-questions](/questions/tagged/unanswered-questions), and [answer-howto](/questions/tagged/answer-howto).

I understand what an accepted answer is, and also what an unanswered question is. However, I don't know the difference between "advice" about an answer, what is an "appropriate" answer, or a "howto" for answers. I don't even see how they're much more use than just posts about answers. Shall we burninate "answering-advice", "appropriate-answers" and "answer-howto"?

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

No, I can't tell them apart.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

It's on-topic for meta, yes.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

A very small amount.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a problem with any of those tags, and I'm not even certain that the lack of any information for them is much of a problem either, I'm afraid. However, I haven't checked whether the existing questions which use these tags follow common sense.

All these tags serve different purposes, and I believe that apart from the overarching [answers](/questions/tagged/answers) tag, there is not a great deal of overlap. I don't see any harm in grouping [answering-advice](/questions/tagged/answering-advice) questions together, and allowing those questions to be distinguished from [accepted-answer](/questions/tagged/accepted-answer).

- [answers](/questions/tagged/answers)

  The question asks about answers. Might go with [support](/questions/tagged/support) or [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), and could even be paired with other tags.
- [answering-advice](/questions/tagged/answering-advice)

  The question asks "How should I have approached answering?" Might go with [support](/questions/tagged/support) or [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion).
- [accepted-answer](/questions/tagged/accepted-answer)

  Paired with [support](/questions/tagged/support), this is for questions like "How do I unaccept an answer?" (also see below) or "Why didn't I get my +15 or +2 rep?", which would also need the [reputation](/questions/tagged/reputation) tag. Paired with [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), this might be used for "Why was this answer accepted?" or "How do we unaccept an answer which is obviously wrong?"
- [unanswered-questions](/questions/tagged/unanswered-questions)

  This is for Meta questions about questions which do not have an answer (perhaps "Is this question actually answerable?"), or which Community ♦ has bumped because of its criteria.
- [answer-howto](/questions/tagged/answer-howto)

  This is for asking about what steps to follow in order to post an answer, or maybe how to accept an answer. It would almost certainly be paired with [support](/questions/tagged/support).

Comment: Yours is more detailed, I'll stop writing mine. +1